# Very simple regex match takes forever to compute

Tags: c#, regex, performance

This following code takes forever to execute.

```
var input = "105,106,109,110,111,112,113,114,115,116,117,118,1423,1424s,1426,1427,1429,1431,34,39,44s";
var pattern = new Regex(@"^(-?[0-9]+,?)+$");

var stopWatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
var result = pattern.IsMatch(input);
stopWatch.Stop();

Console.WriteLine("Finished matching in {0}ms. Result: {1}", stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds, result);
```

When there's less numbers (or numbers with `s` on the end), the matching is done more quickly.

What's going on there?

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html

Comment: @KeithHall: Thanks, Keith. I think this might be it.

Comment: you can fix it by changing the `(` to an atomic group - `(?>`

Comment: It is for sure catastrophic backtracking since the `-` and `,` are optional and the whole pattern gets "reduced" to `(\d+)+`. Try `^(?<s>-?[0-9]+)(?:,(?<s>-?[0-9]+))*$` (if you need to access the capture collection).

Comment: @KeithHall: Thanks, the atomic groups work just fine. I'll have to read up more on that.